# Spring 3.2.3 MBeanExporter doesn't honor bean property

Tags: java, spring, spring-jmx

I exported a bean via Spring MBeanExporter, this bean implements NotificationEmitter and behaves like it was a NotificationBroadcasterSupport. So it esposes the method public MBeanNotificationInfo[] getNotificationInfo(), returning a static instance of MBeanNotificationInfo[] that holds it's own notifTypes, just one string dot annotated. Loking at this bean through jconsole, instead of the configured notifTypes, I see:

```
ModelMBeanNotificationInfo: GENERIC ... Types: jmx.modelmbean.generic
ModelMBeanNotificationInfo: ATTRIBUTE_CHANGE ... Types: jmx.attribute.change
```

Also, if I subscribe notificatios via jconsole, I never see that addNotificationListener implemented method has been called.
Looking at the bean code via debug, I never see any NotificationEmitter method called. While all other methods of that bean behave as expected.
What does MBeanExporter do this figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arise setting the property *assembler* of  the *MBeanExporter* bean, in particular setting the property *interfaceMappings* of *assembler*. If the class name of the bean added to *MBeanExporter* and the interface name in the *assembler* don't math the rule interfaceName = className+"MBean" a new MBean that implements *NotificationEmitter* is created and regisetred into MBeanServer. Following the above rule the bean supplied with *MBeanExporter* is registered instead.
This because *MBeanServer* while registerin, check the above rule and throws a *NotCompliantMBeanException* if it founds a mimatch.